# Retrieving data in ruby on rails through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, model-associations

I have three tables  Users(contains users details)  users_shifts(contains users shift mapping) and shift(it's id is in users_shift table). 
What I'm doing is assigning multiple shifts to users and i want to retrieve all the data from users, users_shift and shift table.
I have done the following thing :

In user model:

```
has_many :users_shifts, :dependent => :destroy
```

In users_shift model :

```
has_one :shift
belongs_to :user
```

In Shift Model

```
belongs_to :users_shift
```

In controller i have :

```
User.all
```

Now i want to fetch all the data in a table in view.
I have to display users and his shift. Users detail will come from users table and shifts details will come from shifts table. Users_shift is used for users shift mapping.

Comment: I have to display users and his shift. Users detail will come from users table and shifts details will come from shifts table. Users_shift is used for users shift mapping.

Comment: I think what @Dipak  says is pretty much it. If not please elaborate your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in your console first

```
@user_shifts = @user.users_shifts # by using this you get all users_shifts details for that particular user.
@shift = @user_shift.shift # by using this you will get shift for that paricular user_shift
```

same way you can also

```
@shift.user_shift # for getting details for users_shifts
@user_shifts.user # for getting details about user
```

Comment: I'm able to receive that shift mapping but not that corresponding shift. Whenever I'm using @user_shift.shift.start_time its giving me this error "undefined method `start_time' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I got the users and shift mapping data where for 1 user there are multiple shifts. But i'm still not getting the shift detail.i didn't get this '@shift.user_shift' can you please elaborate.

Comment: if user have multiple shifts then you have to define relationship for user and shift then you can get data. at this time i thing you are not giving relationship between user and shifts.

Comment: There is no relation between users table and shifts table.Shift is simply giving start and end time of different shifts whose id is stored in users_shift table.The main relation is between user and users_shift table where a user can have multiple shifts.

Comment: I just want that shifts value gets joined to users_shifts values whose shift_id is in users_shift table.

Comment: now i m confuse .. user and  shift have a HABTM  relatinship ?

Comment: see this link -> relationship -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and for HABTM -> http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many